# A problem related to combinatorics and number theory

Tags: combinatorics

$n$ and $m$ are two numbers. We have to make $n$ with $m$ numbers (only taking their sum). For example, if $n=6$, $m=3$, $6$ is formed with $3$ numbers in the following way:
$$
1+1+4=6 \\
2+2+2=6 \\
1+2+3=6
$$
For every element of the sets above, if we use $C(r,2)$, $0<r<n$ and take their summation we get like this.

$$
C(1,2)+C(1,2)+C(4,2)=0+0+6=6 \\
C(2,2)+C(2,2)+C(2,2)=3 \\
C(1,2)+C(2,2)+C(3,2)=4
$$

Here,we have considered $C(1,2)=0$.

We notice that if we make $n$ with $m−1$ $1$'s plus $n−(m−1)$, then the sum of $C(r,2)$ will be maximum. For this reason, the sum for $(1,1,4)$,
$6$, is maximum. I have checked different value of $n$ and $m$ and for every case I have got the sum of $C(r,2)$ of the combination: $m−1$ $1$'s plus $n−(m−1)$
is maximum .

Can anyone prove that why it happens with better explanation?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we pick $m$ numbers $r_1,r_2,\ldots,r_m$ such that $r_1+r_2+\cdots+r_m = n$.

Then, $\displaystyle\sum_{k = 1}^{m}\dbinom{r_k}{2} = \sum_{k = 1}^{m}\dfrac{r_k^2-r_k}{2} = \dfrac{1}{2}\sum_{k = 1}^{m}r_k^2 - \dfrac{1}{2}\sum_{k = 1}^{m}r_k = \dfrac{1}{2}\sum_{k = 1}^{m}r_k^2 - \dfrac{n}{2}$.

So, maximizing $\displaystyle\sum_{k = 1}^{m}\dbinom{r_k}{2}$ is equivalent to maximizing $\displaystyle\sum_{k = 1}^{m}r_k^2$.

Suppose for some $i,j$ we have $r_i \le r_j$. Let's pick a new set of numbers $s_1,s_2,\ldots,s_m$ where $s_i = r_i - 1$, $s_j = r_j+1$, and $s_k = r_k$ for all $k \neq i,j$. (i.e. we decrease the smaller number by $1$ and increase the larger number by $1$.) Then, $s_1+s_2+\cdots+s_m = n$, however,

$\displaystyle\sum_{k = 1}^{m}s_k^2 = s_i^2+s_j^2+\sum_{\substack{k = 1\\k \neq i,j}}^{m}s_k^2 = (r_i-1)^2+(r_j+1)^2+\sum_{\substack{k = 1\\k \neq i,j}}^{m}r_k^2$

$= r_i^2-2r_i+1+r_j^2+2r_j+1+\displaystyle\sum_{\substack{k = 1\\k \neq i,j}}^{m}r_k^2 = 2(r_j-r_i)+2+\sum_{k = 1}^{m}r_k^2 > \sum_{k = 1}^{m}r_k^2$

So, by decreasing the smaller number and increasing the larger number, we increase the sum of the squares of the numbers.

Therefore, $\displaystyle\sum_{k = 1}^{m}r_k^2$ is maximized when one of the $r_k$'s is as large as possible. If you restrict the $r_k$'s to being positive integers, then you will have $m-1$ ones and one $n-(m-1)$.